# NServiceBus & Bootstrapper StructureMap

Tags: structuremap, nservicebus, bootstrapper

I am using `NServiceBus` is an azure worker role via convention by having configuration in `app.config` and azure Queue details in .csdef.

I have a rest service that accesses the IBus by doing this:

```
Configure.Instance.Builder.Build<IBus>()
```

and works fine!

I have a class that implements `IWantToRunAtStartup` where I do the configure bootstrapper as follows:

```
    Bootstrapper.With.StructureMap()
        .UsingAutoRegistration()
        .And.AutoMapper().Start();
```

I'm losing the IBus reference if I then use the bootstrap container:

```
Configure.Instance.StructureMapBuilder((IContainer) Bootstrapper.Container);
```

How do I use `Bootsrtrapper.StructureMap` and `NServiceBus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telling us which container you want to use needs to be done from a `IConfigureThisEndpoint` and `IWantCustomInitialization` class, example:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With()
            .StructureMapBuilder((IContainer) Bootstrapper.Container);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi John - must be a single class and not two seperate, so as above but also the serializer as .AzureMessageQueue().JsonSerializer(); Great cheers.